# Executar método de log sempre que ocorrer Exception ASP.NET MVC (Exception Handling)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exceção

Preciso implementar Log erro na minha aplicação **ASP.NET MVC**, Minha dúvida é a seguinte, existe alguma forma de eu acionar um método (Seria este um método que gravaria o log de erro, enviaria o e-mail e afins a tratativa da exception) sempre que ocorrer uma **Exception** em qualquer parte do meu código não necessariamente este estando dentro de um bloco de **try catch**.
Exemplo:

```
//Este método fica na "Escuta" a espera de que ocorra uma exception em qualquer parte do código
public void Exception_Listener(Exception ex){
//Grava o log de erro
GravarLogErro(ex);
}
```

A idéia disto é que eu use a chamado do método GravarLogErro() em somente uma parte da aplicação, E não em todos os meus Blocos de Try Catch, Pois se caso implementar um parâmetro a mais neste método eu teria revirar todos os Try Catch da aplicação para poder informar o parâmetro.

Espero que me entendam.
Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Pelo que entendi voce tem a opção de configurar isto no Global.asax eou Web.config, e pegar os erros via Exception ex = Server.GetLastError(); veja esse post no stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null

Comment: @Edenilson Eu também sempre tive essa dúvida ao criar as minhas soluções para logs. E eu uso o Web Forms. Então, caso alguém possa da uma resposta considerando o Web Forms.

Comment: @DiegoMoreno veja este link, Ele ensina o mesmo vários tipos de aplicação vai lhe atender:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pessoal consegui da seguinte forma: Para capturar erros em ASP.NET MVC no Global Asax tem que por o seguinte método:
O link a seguir ensina a utilizar do mesmo em outros tipos de aplicação:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx

```
private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError()
        //Seu método de gravar log
    }
```

Toda vez que for acionada uma exceção automaticamente cairá neste método.
No meu caso funcionou assim perfeitamente.

Comment: poderia também fazer um filtro Global. e-ou criar atributos caso apenas em algumas controllers queira colocar esse sistem ade log, algo como